# How can I show <li> only if custom field has content

Tags: php, customization, plugin-types

I have the following code:

```
<font size="2">Pistas:</font></p>
<ul>
<li>
  <?php

echo types_render_field("pista-1a", array("argument1"=>"value1","argument2"=>"value2","argument2"=>"value2"));

?><li>
<?php

echo types_render_field("pista-1b", array("argument1"=>"value1","argument2"=>"value2","argument2"=>"value2"));

?> </li></ul>       '
```

As you can see... I manually inserted

in every item, but sometimes not all fields have contents, so in this case, the

bullets show with no content in front of them.. how can I change the code to insert

only if the custom field is not empty.... (I'm using Types Plugin)

Sorry for my basic coding, I'm not a programmer and I'm learning a little as I try to adapt my theme to my needs

Thanks a lot folks!

Comment: I'm not sure about Advanced Custom Fields but you may be able to store types_render_field() in a variable then test if it's empty: `$type = types_render_field(...)` `if( ! empty( $type ) ) : // show LI`

Comment: sorry McGee... But I didnt quite understand where to put it... can you give me an example based on my codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, I'm not familiar with Advanced Custom Fields but you may be able to store the returned value into a variable then test if that variable is empty, like so:

```
<?php
    $pista1a = types_render_field("pista-1a", array("argument1"=>"value1","argument2"=>"value2","argument2"=>"value2"));
?>
<ul>

  <?php if( ! empty( $pista1a ) ) : ?>

    <li>
        <?php echo $pista1a; ?>
    </li>

  <?php endif; ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: awesome...thanks!!... I'll try and let you know how it worked out!